# How to get source packages from dir in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

What is the way to get the name of the package which creates specific dir under /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ on Ubuntu

For example I am trying to get the package name which installs `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common/` or `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common/decrypt.sh`

can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: `dpkg -L /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hdinsight_common`: http://superuser.com/questions/179353/how-do-i-find-out-which-package-owns-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dpkg -S <path...>` for installed packages, or `apt-file search <paths...>` for packages that might not be installed.